# Updating header after log in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I  created a shopping website in reactjs where I have divided the app.js file in to header ,routes and footer.the router is by default redirected to welcome page.But after I login I am redirecting my page to the same welcome page.but then I am not able to update my header with user name and logout by updating the existing nav.i know it is because of the fact that the header is not getting rerendered.But can some one help me to some how make it rerender?

Comment: It is better show us some of your code. Where do you keep your login state? You can render your Header component with two conditions: 1. Not logged in 2. Logged in.

Comment: once user logs i have set username in a service.js file.i want to render this in the header

Comment: I don't know how convenient to keep your state like this. You should use React's internal state or better something like Redux to keep and manage your state, since authentication information can be used in many places in your app. In your case, how do you plan to get user login info from that file? How your Header component will get related info?

Comment: This is my first work in react.So for now i what i have planned is like keeping the username and token in a file and append the token to requests and use this name to add to username in the header.Please suggest if you have any good options for me :)

Comment: I am not a pro but I can suggest that, learn the React way :) Somehow your front end should keep your login state. Maybe you can use localStorage for a simple authentication system but that means you need to read that info every time where do you want to use. Here state is get involved. Before trying to code something like authentication first grasp the React side and if you think you need deeper state (probably you will, learn Redux).

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use `redux`.

> **Redux** is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.
>
> It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in
>   different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to
>   test. On top of that, it provides a great developer experience, such
>   as live code editing combined with a time traveling debugger.
>
> You can use Redux together with React, or with any other view library.
>   It is tiny (2kB, including dependencies).

There are many topics about `redux`. 
there is a function called: `mapStateToProps`. 
suppose you have a `action` (login,logout,addToCart,removeToCart etc.) at `A` component.
You want to `B` and `C` listen to your actions. for example when user do logout, you want to remove `username` of your header. at this here `redux` helps you!